# How do I disable Intel power management in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04

Guten Tag,

I have two Thinkpads (x200 and x200s) and both suffer from a strange coil whine noise. It is really quite noticeable and can be really annoying at times.

After doing some research I found out that this is caused by the Intel power management setting in the bios which reduces power consumption when idle. I switched it off in the bios and the noise was gone! But this would mean sacrificing a lot of battery power (I saw an example where it went from 3.5 hours to 2).

I was wondering if there's a way in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to disable this power management feature *only when plugged in*. I could then have a quiet Pc at home and it would only make that noise on the go, where it doesn't matter as much.

Does anyone have an idea?

Cheers

(edit: my bios version is 3.22 (6DET72WW), I don't know whether this is relevant or not, but here it is anyway)

Comment: Maybe [TLP](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html) can help you?

Comment: I tried TLP but it only made my Pc freeze and crash pretty often. Seems like it's a Thinkpad related issue...